# Problemas para enviar enlace

Tags: php, html5

He creado un `html` el cual es la plantilla donde se muestra el objeto que esta almacenado en el `localsorage`, obviamente como la información que se visualizará en pantalla la extraigo de un archivo .json al querer compartir ese enlace con otra persona solamente se va a mostrar lo que está en el archivo más no el contenido de lo que yo estoy viendo.

esto es el código en el archivo.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
   <title>PRODUCTO</title>
   <?php require('./layout/head.php') ?>
</head>

<body>
   <?php require('./layout/header.php') ?>
   <main class="principal">
      <div class="cont_total">
         <div class="cont-general">
            <div class="direccion-producto">
               <h3 id="direccionProducto"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content-prod">
               <div class="content-imgs">
                  <div class="cont-img">
                     <img class="img-princip" id="imgPrincipal" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="grupo-imgs">
                     <img class="img-mnt-prod" id="miniatura1" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
                     <img class="img-mnt-prod" id="miniatura2" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
                     <img class="img-mnt-prod" id="miniatura3" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
                     <img class="img-mnt-prod" id="miniatura4" src="RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="info-producto">
                  <div class="titulo-producto">
                     <h1 id="tituloProducto"></h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="breve-caract" id="brevesCaract">
                     <ul></ul>
                  </div>
                  <div id="cont_btn_cotiza">
                     <button class="btn_cotiza">cotizar</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="valor-cant-agregar" id="valor-cant-agregar">
                     <form class="form-valor-cant-agregar" action="" method="GET">
                        <div class="valor-producto">
                           <i class="icon-dollar"></i><label for="PVP" id="precioProd"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cantidad-producto">
                           <label for="num-cant-prod">Cantidad: </label>
                           <input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="5" name="num-cant-prod" id="num-cant-prod" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="boton-agrega-producto">
                           <a id="ancla"><i class="agrega-carro icon-cart-plus" type="submit" name="btn-agrega-carro" id="btn-agrega-carro"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="notas-generales">
                     <ul>
                        <li>Envíos a todo el ECUADOR mediante servientrega desde $4.00. (El valor depende de la ubicación de destino, peso y volumen del paquete.)</li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-producto_segundaParte">
               <div class="titulo-mas-caract">
                  <h2>ficha técnica</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="link" id="link">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" id="enlaceEXT">Página del fabricante</a>
               </div>
               <div class="mas-caract" id="masCaract">
                  <ul></ul>
               </div>
               <div class="prod-relacionados" id="prod-relacionados">
                  <div class=" titulo-prod-relacionados">
                     <h2>productos relacionados</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div id="carruselProdRela">
                     <div class="MS-content" id="relacionados"></div>
                     <div class="MS-controls">
                        <button class="MS-left"><i class="icon-left-open"></i></button>
                        <button class="MS-right"><i class="icon-right-open"></i></button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cover_principal" id="coverPrincipal">
         <?php require_once('./emergentes.php') ?>
      </div>
   </main>
   <?php require('./layout/footer.php') ?>
   <?php require('./layout/esencial_js.php') ?>
   <!-- <script src="JS/producto.js"></script> -->
   <script src="JS/carruseles_prdR.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="JS/reemplazarBtnCot.js"></script> -->
   <script src="JS/vCotizar.js"></script>
   <script src="JS/frmCotiza.js"></script>
   <script>
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="JS/producto.js?cb=' + cachebuster + '" ></scr' + 'ipt>');
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="JS/reemplazarBtnCot.js?cb=' + cachebuster + '" ></scr' + 'ipt>');
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

y como ven no hay datos "quemados" de un artículo en específico, quisiera saber alguna forma de obtener el enlace de lo que yo estoy viendo actualmente.

[(link: http://pcmasters-ec.com/v_producto.php) este sería el link que deseo enviar a otra persona. Sé que simplemente se visualizará lo que yo llamo como plantilla, pero si se va al inicio se puede abrir cualquier item y en otro pág se cargará lo de la plantilla con los datos que utilizo como clave para que se lea y eso es lo que deseo que la otra persona pueda visualizar.

Digo de esta forma, esperando me pueda a dar a entender de otro modo]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea que me pueda ayudar a conseguir este objetivo?

Comment: define que es lo que "yo estoy actualmente viendo"

Comment: tendrias que crear un subsistema para compartir datos mediante la URL en ese caso tu busqueda debe estar guardada en algun lugar como una base de datos ejemplo: token=jhasdgfkjagshfjashdfg y asiciar en alguna columna el filtro que usaste y el producto;

Comment: no basta con pasarle la url `v_producto.php` tendrias que pasarle los argumentos como: `v_producto.php?token=jhasdgfkjagshfjashdfg` he identificar en el backend ese token para que automaticamente haga y muestre tu busqueda ...

Comment: no es complejo pero tampo es corto ....

Comment: Gracias ArcanisGK507, me diste algunas ideas para poder continuar con esto